# Using only Git to Deploy Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment

I am new at Rails development, and have created my first (simple) app that I would like to host on my Linode VPS.  I am trying to figure out a good but easy way to deploy to my production server.

I use BitBucket and Git for version control, and would like to do a `git pull` and `touch tmp/restart.txt` on my VPS everytime I want to make an update.

I have two questions:

First, is this a legitimate way to depoy my Rails app?
Second, it seems like Capistrano is overkill for a small app like this one.  Am I wrong about this?

Comment: I personally have deployed about a dozen apps the way you have explained, commercial and personal, it its an overhead to have to login, and do a git pull every time you want to update, but if you feel thats the way your would prefer, there shouldn't be any problems. After all you can always revisit other alternative deploy methods.

Comment: I wouldn't say capistrano is an overkill. After all if you wrote your application in Rails it isn't so small. Just Rails itself are one of the larger frameworks:). Anyway good alternative to capistrano is mina (http://nadarei.co/mina/). The most beautiful thing about mina is that it works really fast.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I will use the `git pull` approach until I get more comfortable with Capistrano.